# For to configure matplotlib subplots within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to loop through some data in a Pandas dataframe and plot into different subplots, but not quite sure what I've got wrong.

Here's the code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for i, col in enumerate(df2.columns):
    print(col)
    axes[i] = df2[col].plot(kind="box")
```

[image]

How can I fill up the other subplots?

Comment: df2[col].plot(kind="box", ax = axes[I])?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this, you just need to do `df.plot` with the option `subplots=True` and then change there the outlier, vertical (`layout=(4,1)`):

```
df2.plot(kind='box',subplots=True, layout=(4,1), figsize=(8,8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you prefer the subplots to be distributed horizontally (`layout=(1,4)`):

```
df2.plot(kind='box',subplots=True, layout=(1,4),figsize=(15,8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

And finally, you could put all boxplots together just by:

```
df2.plot(kind='box', figsize=(8,8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

For more info about how to make visualization with pandas check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the axis as argument to the plot function. Something along these lines:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for i, col in enumerate(df2.columns):
    print(col)
    df2[col].plot(kind="box", ax=axes[i])
```

In your example, you are redefining the elements of ´axes´. Instead, you define axes once and then you tell the plot function which axis to use for the plot.